# Django Model foreign key

Tags: model

```
class Mcq_Question(models.Model):   
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Mcq_Choice(models.Model):
    mcq_question = models.ForeignKey(Mcq_Question, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mcq_choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mcq_choice_text



class Mcq_Answer(models.Model):
    mcq_question = models.OneToOneField(Mcq_Question)
    mcq_choice = models.OneToOneField(Mcq_Choice)

    def __str__(self):      

        return str(self.mcq_question) + "    " + str(self.mcq_answer)
```

First i need to say i am very new at django 
Here one MCQ ques has only One correct mcq_choice answer and the answer is stored in Mcq_Answer Model.
My problem is in Mcq_Answer Model:
the answer of the question should be one of the choices of the question
If i use this model then in the django admin panel i can choose mcq_answer  for a mcq_question i have all the mcq_choice available for a mcq_question.
If a mcq_ques has 4 choice then the mcq_anserwer_choice can not be any thing other than those 4 choices.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an attribute on you choice to mark the correct answer(s) so you don't need the separate answer class.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.